# Method of passing url variables from APIView class to serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need to get the variables passed to the url and pass them to the serializer for further processing. I know how to process these variables in a views, but not in a serializer.

**urls.py**

```
path('upload_excel_rfi/<str:rfiid>/<int:vendor>/<int:analyst>/', UploadElementFromExcelFile.as_view()
```

**views.py**

```
class UploadElementFromExcelFile(APIView):
    serializer_class = ElementCommonInfoSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # GET VARIABLES
    rfiid = kwargs.get('rfiid')
    vendor = kwargs.get('vendor')
    analyst = kwargs.get('analyst')
    data = request.data  # response data is list of dict
    try:
        # implement transaction  - if exception appear during for loop iteration none data save to DB
        with transaction.atomic():
            ....some logic
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
    except ValidationError:
        return Response({"errors": (serializer.errors,)},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ElementCommonInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Elements
        fields = ("...")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        .....
        return self
```

I found a mention of `def get_serializer_context(self)`, but as I understood this method is not used with APIView. Would you mind telling me how to transfer additional variables correctly ? I now about the way to add extra variable `context= {}` to serializer

```
context = {"rfiid": kwargs.get('rfiid')}
serializer = BlaBlaSerializer(data=data, context=context)
```

But I'm wondering if there's another, more DRY-appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializer_class` doesn't do anything in the `APIView` of DRF.
You can pass additional context to the serializer like so:

```py
serializer = ElementCommonInfoSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
```

and then in your serializer.

```py
class ElementCommonInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Elements
        fields = ("...")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        ...
        return self
```

Comment: I know this way, I wrote about it in a question. Is he really the only one? If there are no other options, I'll mark yours as the answer)

Comment: you could use `serializer.create(serializer.validated_data, param1, param2)` and overload your serializer `create` function.

Comment: with what was provided in the question, this is the correct way to do it.